# Why isn't the anim montage playing when the enemy reaches the player?

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5, unreal-development-kit

I'm new to using Unreal Engine 5, and I'm working on a small game project for a university project.

I'm working on the basics of programming enemy AI at the moment, and I've ran into a problem.

As the title suggests, the animation montage for the enemy's attack animation isn't playing once it reaches the player character.

I've provided an image below to show what my event graph looks like.
[Image of event graph from enemy's blueprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6N6U.png)

The goal is to have the enemy attack once they reach the player, but so far this isn't happening. The enemy instead, once he sees the player, chases the player while using his movement animations. Once the enemy reaches the player, he just stands there staring at the player.

Any help would be appreciated. If you think that there are no errors in my event graph then I'll look elsewhere for errors, or try to provide more information to help solve this. Thanks.